# How do I blit a rectangular outline to a surface?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an obstruction tile/sprite and I want to draw a rectangular outline (32x32 or from its image rect) directly to its image surface. Ideally the colors and outline/border width will also be taken into consideration.

```
class Obstruction(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/tile.png").convert_alpha()
        if s.DEBUG:
            outline = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
            self.image.blit(outline, (0, 0))
```

Few things I've tried:

1. The code above generates a filled rectangle rather than an outline.
2. The prominent answer I found online is with the use of `pygame.draw.rect()` but this does not blit directly to the image.
3. I've tried creating rect1 and rect2 and did subtraction between their areas using https://www.pygame.org/wiki/SubtractRects, however the result is a Rect object which can't be blit into a Surface object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a black rectangular outline on the image with [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect). The las parameter of `pygame.draw.rect` is optional and is the with of the line:

```py
class Obstruction(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/tile.png").convert_alpha()
        if s.DEBUG:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.image, "black", (0, 0, 32, 32), 1)
```

Comment: It worked. I always thought of using ```pygame.draw.rect(main_screen, "black", (0, 0, 32, 32), 1)```, but the main_screen always gets covered up by new frames. Passing the image itself totally slipped my mind.